# Unexpected token in docker logs after docker run

Tags: docker

After running:

```
docker run -d nodeapi -p 49160:3000
```

The container doesnt start and when I look at docker logs I see the error:

```
[eval]:1
49160:3000

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

edit: I'm running that on Windows 10 via Docker Toolbox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-p 49160:3000` needs to be before the container image `nodeapi`. The way you have it, `-p 49160:3000` is passed to the container's `npm start` as if it were command-line flags|params. Clearly, it doesn't like the colon.

So.

```sh
docker run --detach --publish 49160:3000 nodeapi
```

While you debug, it may be preferable to run the container interactively:

```sh
docker run --interactive --tty --publish=49160:3000 nodeapi
```